# Can anyone explain to me why each is pointing to the same thing?

Tags: c

I was just messing around in C when I encountered this problem:

```
typedef struct {
    int val;
} Test;

typedef struct {
    Test* p;
} P;

int main() {
    int a = 0;
    P list[5];
    while (a <= 5) {
        Test new_test = {a};
        list[a].p = &new_test;
        ++a;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        printf("%d ", list[i].p->val);
    }
}
```

For some reason each value in the array is pointing to the same thing.

The output I expected was something like:

```
1 2 3 4 5
```

Instead I got:

```
5 5 5 5 5
```

Anyone know the reason for this?

Comment: `new_test` a block local variable, that is "recreated" each loop. In your case it happens to be recreated at the same stack location. Your code has an undefined behavior anyway,

Comment: Also, your while loop iterates over 6 items, when it should be 5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The variable

```
Test new_test = {a};
```

is local to the block used as the loop body and its life ends on end of execution of the block, so dereferencing pointers pointing at the after execution of the block ends is illegal.

It looks like the compiler decided to reuse some of the memory space for each iteration.

To avoid this, allocate objects in a way that persists until you finish using them.

Also `list[5]` is out-of-range for `P list[5];` and accessing the "element" is illegal. You have to allocate more elements to avoid out-of-range access.

```
/* add required headers */
#include <stdio.h> /* printf() */
#include <stdlib.h> /* malloc() */

typedef struct {
    int val;
} Test;

typedef struct {
    Test* p;
} P;

int main() {
    int a = 0;
    P list[5 + 1]; /* allocate enough element */
    while (a <= 5) {
        /* allocate non-local object */
        Test* new_test = malloc(sizeof(*new_test));
        if (new_test == NULL) return 1;
        new_test->val = a;
        list[a].p = new_test;
        ++a;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        printf("%d ", list[i].p->val);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Can you explain what the line 'malloc(sizeof(*new_test));' does? And is it any different from doing malloc(sizeof(Test))?

Comment: @th6322 `malloc(sizeof(*new_test))` allocates the size of what is pointed at by `new_test`. It is equivalent to `malloc(sizeof(Test)` in this case. The difference is what is used for `sizeof`: an expression is used in the first case while a type name is used in second.